# Connection data between two dropdown

Tags: cognito-forms

How to make two or more data connection each other?

Example:

```
Grade       Teachers
1           Smith
            Mary
            Kelvin

2           Bob
            Harry
            Sue
            Dave
```

I make drop down and select Grade 1, Display Grade 1 teacher on another drop down and pick a teacher name.  Can it be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not have the ability to populate a Choice field with values form outside of the preset choice field options. This is a feature that you can follow our progress on our via our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/vKfb0oVP).